# decomposing a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$ be the homomorphism given by $\phi(k)=[nk]m$.  Decompose $\phi$. They want us to find the following:

$\alpha: \operatorname{im} \phi \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$ is a monomorphism.

$\beta: \mathbb{Z}/\ker \phi \rightarrow \operatorname{im} \phi$ is an isomorphism.

$\gamma: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/\ker \phi$ is an epimorphism.

I believe the kernel is the cyclic subgroup generate by $m$ and that the image is just the group $\mathbb{Z}_m$, but I do not know how to write the three things so in the end we get $\phi = \alpha \times \beta \times \gamma$.

Comment: I've latex-ed up your post. Makes it look nice, and easier to read. However, you have an issue with the last line - you should use $\circ$ for function composition rather than $\times$ (the code is `\circ`). Also, I do not understand your definition of $\phi$. Do you mean $k\mapsto k\text{ mod }m$ and are just using a notation I have not come across?

Comment: I guess $[n k]m$ means $[n k]_{m}$, the class of $nk$ modulo $m$.

Comment: (As for solving your problem, you are right that the kernel is cyclic generated by $m$ and that the image is the whole of $\mathbb{Z}_m$. Now, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are related to the first isomorphism theorem - have you come across that yet? While $\alpha$ is actually just the trivial map (because $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ *is* \mathbb{Z}_m). Now, to understand this question, in some ways the best thing you can do is sit down with a pen and paper and plug in some numbers. For example, take $m=5$ and $k=2$, and then $m=6$ and $k=2$, and then $m=100$ and $k=123$.)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Ah, yes, of course, I hadn't thought about subscripts. I'll leave it to the OP to correct though.